# Send result from called powershell script to a calling powershell script

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to send just the result I want from a called PowerShell script back to the calling script.

So the script `testcaller.ps1`

```
$Result = Invoke-Expression "$PSScriptRoot\testcalled"
$LogMessage = "TestCalled ended with Result $Result"
Write-Output $LogMessage
```

Calls the script `testcalled.ps1`

```
$TestMessage = "this is a test"
Write-Output $TestMessage
$Level = 1
exit $Level
```

When run it produces this...

TestCalled ended with Result this is a test
0

I have two problems. I get the testmessage passed back to my calling script and the level past back is 0 when it should be 1. What I want to see is...

TestCalled ended with Result 1

Comment: you can try to use return:
$TestMessage = "this is a test"
$Level = 1
return $TestMessage, $Level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given **`testcalled.ps1`**

```
'hello world'
function Say-Hello { 'hello!' }
exit 1
```

If you want to run this external script from another script you can either [`dot source`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.2#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) it:

> The functions, variables, aliases, and drives
> that the script creates are created in the scope in which you are
> working. After the script runs, you can use the created items and
> access their values in your session.

```
$Result = . "$PSScriptRoot\testcalled.ps1"
$Result       # => hello world
Say-Hello     # => 'hello!'
$LASTEXITCODE # => 1
```

Or use the [`call operator &`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-):

> The call operator executes in a child scope.

Meaning that, *functions, variables, aliases, and drives* will **not** be available on the current scope.

```
$Result = & "$PSScriptRoot\testcalled.ps1"
$Result       # => hello world
Say-Hello     # => SayHello: The term 'SayHello' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function....
$LASTEXITCODE # => 1
```

As you can see, on both cases, you can use the automatic variable [`$LASTEXITCODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#lastexitcode).

Last, but not least, it is not recommended to use `Invoke-Expression`. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/